# Как создать компоновщик

Tags: компиляция

Всем привет. Вот пишу свой компилятор(в байт код)/интерпретатор, и хотелось бы узнать каким образом на уровне компиляции подключаются статические и динамические библиотеки? Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: На уровне компиляции они вообще не подключаются.

Comment: это как это так? Статические библиотеки тоже??

Comment: Любые. RTFM.